# Why doesn't `datastream['e']` retrieve the desired data here?

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I have this data:

```
datastream = {'data': {'a': 1, 'e': 'BANANA'}}
```

and I type

```
print(datastream['e'])
```

to retrieve `'BANANA'`, but all I get is

```
  File "Test.py", line 123, in main
    print(datastream['e'])
KeyError: 'e'
```

What code should I use instead?

Comment: `print(binance_datastream['data']['e'])`

Comment: My hero, you saved my caffeine addiction <3

Comment: That isn't a "datastream" (it's just a dict where one of the values is a dict); you're missing a closing `}` in describing it; the things you want to get are not called attributes (those are the things you get by using the `.` operator); and the code you write to access the data is not called a "command". Also, please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to *read* and *understand* error messages. If you think you have used a correct key for a dict, but are getting a `KeyError`, you should *be able to figure out for yourself* to *check what keys exist*.

Comment: Also: welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask]. Do not "tag" your question in the title; that's what the actual tags are for. Try to make sure you are using the correct tags - `dataframe` is for Pandas, which doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question. Also keep in mind that this is *not a discussion forum*; we like questions to be clear, specific and *to the point*.